# Connecting desktop app to online database via php

Tags: php, mysql, database, desktop, juce

I've read a lot of posts on this general subject but I still can't seem to figure it out.

I'm building a Mac/PC desktop application. When a user first authorizes the app, I want to store their info in an online Mysql database. I'm using the JUCE library to call and handle a php file online which in turn handles the updating of the online database. On my desktop app:

```
String url = "http://www.syntorial.com/onlinePHPFileToCall.php?email=" + email + "&computer=" + SystemStats::getComputerName();
URL authURL(url);
InputStream *input = authURL.createInputStream(true);
String result = input->readString();
```

And the php file:

```
<?php

$result = "";

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','dbname');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    $result = "connection failed";
}
else
{
    $mysqli->select_db("UserInfo");

    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $computer = $_GET['computer'];

    $query = "UPDATE UserInfo SET computer = '$computer' WHERE email = '$email'";

    if ($queryResult = $mysqli->query($query))
    {
        $result = "true";
    }
    else
    {
        $result = "false";
    }
}

echo $result;
?>
```

The result comes back "true" on my desktop app, but the information doesn't actually get saved into the database. If instead of

```
InputStream *input = authURL.createInputStream(true);
```

I use:

```
authURL.launchInDefaultBrowser();
```

it opens up the php file in a browser and everything works fine. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're using mysqli, which is great, but you're using it in a very dangerous way. **Always** use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) your SQL statements. Never, **ever** put unescaped user data in your query.

Comment: Thanks tadman. That's next on my to do list, after I get this thing working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the "true" argument in CreateInputStream was telling it to use POST data instead of GET so the call was ignoring the GET data. Thanks the help.

Comment: You can Click on the Up arrow if the comments or response helped you, thats the best way to say Thanks. :) You should also go ahead and accept one response as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Joe, 
 
Seems like one of your first question on this forum. So Welcome. You mentioned you want to store information in an online database. But while connecting you added db information about your local via

```
mysqli('localhost',
```

. Update localhost to point to an online database by finding its ip address/servername, username and password. Also you will have to ensure the computer where you run this application can connect to that online db.

Here is what I am ran on my local and worked for me.

```
<?php

$result = "";

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    $result = "connection failed";
}
else
{

    $email = "xyz@yahoo.com";
    $computer = "1mycomp";

    $query = "UPDATE so1 SET computer = '$computer' WHERE email = '$email'";

    /* 
      Printing the query to check what is being executed. 
      Remove the below line after program works.
    */
    echo $query;

    if ($queryResult = $mysqli->query($query))
    {
        $result = "true";
    }
    else
    {
        $result = "false";
    }
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response pal4life. As mentioned, if I launch this php file from a browser everything works correctly, so I don't think there's anything wrong with the query structures or 'localhost', etc. I tried echoing the $query but it was blank, so no info there.

Comment: Check this example here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php. Thus the line $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','dbname'); already has the dbname so unsure why you would need the select_db? Echo query should print atleast something. Try with this updated example and let me know what happens

Comment: Will do first chance I get, thanks. Question though, if what you say is is the problem, wouldn't my code not work from a browser? I guess I'm just trying to understand why the database reacts differently even though in both cases (desktop and browser) it's receiving the same set of instructions?

Comment: JUCE is a non php library, mostly seems like C++. So tag the question with the appropriate language so those developers can provide their input.

Comment: Right. That's half my problem, is figuring out which component is responsible, juce, php or MySQL. I added the tag.